# How to avoid code duplication in this particular case

Tags: c++, templates, code-duplication

I have these generic classes for 2D geometry:

```
template<class T> struct Point
{
    T x,y;
    //...Various member functions...
    //T modulus() const noexcept { ... } 
    //T dist_from(const Point& other) const noexcept { ... } 
    //...
};

template<class T> class Polygon
{
 public:
    // ...An awful lot of member functions...
    auto size() const noexcept { return vertexes.size(); }
    //T area() const noexcept {...}
    //T perimeter() const noexcept {...}
    //T moment_of_inertia(const Point<T>&) const noexcept {...}
    //void reorder_vertexes() {...}
    //void transform(const Matrix& m) {...}
    // ...

 private:
    std::vector<Point<T>> vertexes;
};
```

They work well and I use them in various part of the project. Now, for a particular application, I need `Polygon` but also need to associate some `data` to each of its vertexes.
Since `Polygon` vertexes can be transformed and reordered I would prefer to avoid the extra work of maintaining a parallel `std::vector` containing the additional `data`.
I would really like to introduce a new class like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fWorGMa45):

```
template<class T, class D> class DecoratedPolygon
{
 public:
    struct DecoratedPoint
    {
        Point<T> point;
        D data;
    };

    // Some specialized member functions...
    const D& get_vertex_decoration(const std::size_t idx) const
    {
        return vertexes.at(idx).data;
    }
    // ...Then same member functions as polygon,
    //    except accessing the '.point'
    auto size() const noexcept { return vertexes.size(); }
    //...

 private:
    std::vector<DecoratedPoint> vertexes;
};
```

My problem whith this is that I don't want to rewrite a slightly modified version of all the member functions of `Polygon`.
How would you approach this particular case? I wonder if there is a zero cost technique to avoid that code duplication, or if simply I'm heading in the wrong way.

Comment: Would you be willing to change to `std::vector<Point<T>*> vertices;`? Then you could derive `DecoratedPoint` from `Point` and `DecoratedPolygon` from `Polygon` with very little redundancy.

Comment: You are inviting bugs by having `DecoratedPolygon` contain **both** `std::vector<DecoratedPoint> vertexes;` and `std::vector<Point<T>> vertexes;`.  A good starting refactor would be to remove `vertexes` from `Polygon`, since derived classes are making it clear that said member variable isn't wanted.

Comment: The obvious solution is to make algorithms, well, algorithms and not member functions. The algorithms would be implemented in terms of an abstraction suitable for the domain in question. You'd still need to implement a few operations each time you define a new implementation of the abstraction but a lot fewer than making the algorithms member functions. That's pretty much the fundamental idea behind STL. Also, make `Polygon` parameterised in terms of `Point` than the numeric representation of `Point`. If you insist the underlying type should be usable use an alias template.

Comment: Why not to add `D data` to the `Point` class in the first place? No need to modify "old" `Point` references, only `Polygon` adaptation in a flat, neat manner.

Comment: @Beta Runtime polymorphism is not exactly zero cost but it's indeed a possible way, thanks for the input!

Comment: @DietmarKühl Move calculations outside of `Polygon` and/or parametrizing it with `Point`. I'll definitely think about both your precious suggestions.

Comment: @bloody That was my initial thought also, a little space overhead to solve my dilemma.

Comment: @MatG: Get inspiration on how the abstraction could look like from STL ranges. I'm not a domain expert in areas involving polygons but I could imagine that they can be treated rather similar to sequences of points in which case you'd probably want to use iterators to access the points. You may want to look at [CGAL's polygon](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon/index.html) to see what others did.

Comment: re "just a little space overhead": madness lies that route! You will find that you will need ever more things to associate with your points. Go the generic way and only pay for what is being used!

Comment: @DietmarKühl That would be a little too sloppy right? Wrong direction. I think you all helped me to find the proper solution

Comment: Unrelated to the question: I notice you are using `vector`'s `at()` function: rather than paying the [probably fairly small] cost of repeatedly checking the access is fine use the subscript operator. If you are concerned about out of range accesses use a debugging version of STL which `assert()`s proper access and/or a suitable sanitizer.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I have still to write that part ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to parameterize the Polygon class to take in the Point type as well:

```
template <class P> class Polygon {
   std::vector<P> vertices
}

template <class T> class Point {
  T x,y;
}
class DecoratedPoint : Point<long> {
  int extraData;
}

Polygon<DecoratedPoint> newPoly;
```

The decorated data would end up coming from the point itself though, so the interface would look a bit different:

```
Polygon {
  P get_point_at_idx( const std::size_t idx) { 
     return points.at(idx)
  }
}

my_poly.get_point_at_idx(0).extraData
```

You'd need to change the implementation of Polygon a bit, but might provide more control longer term.

Comment: Why inheritance? Not just `Point` update?

Comment: @bloody, there might be situations where the poster doesn't want to carry extra data about each Point. Depending on how often they carry extra data and how often they don't, each approach (inheritance vs just directly adding to Point) might make more sense.

Comment: @bloody: It is just implementation inheritance, not for polymorphism. That's generally fine although it incurs the danger of slicing. Of course, the assumption is that `Point<long>` is actually a `public` base class of `DecoratedPoint` rather than `private` one as is currently shown.

Comment: @syazdani Yes, for the sake of resources saving this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, what does "slicing" mean in this context? I've never heard that term used...

Comment: @syazdani: if someone accidentally assigns a `DecoratedPoint` to a `Point<long>` instead of to a `DecoratedPoint` or a `Point<long>&` the part in the derived portion of the `DecoratedPoint` gets _sliced_ off: that’s what is teferred to as _slicing_. I do realize that your `DecoratedPoint` doesn’t really have this problem as it `private`ly inherits from `Point<long>` but in this case the members `x` and `y` are inaccessible from the `Polygon<DecoratedPoint>` and it won’t compile if these members are accesed in the algorithms.